# Error about running Go Tour locally: Couldn't find tour files: could not find go-tour content; check $GOROOT and $GOPATH

Tags: go

`go version go1.12.9 darwin/amd64`

After I installed the `golang.org/x/tour` package, I ran the command `tour` and got an error:

```
Couldn't find tour files: could not find go-tour content; check $GOROOT and $GOPATH
```

Here is the output of `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/elk/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/elk/ccode/go"
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/5d/q9dj2fxx4t71w0g5g00cvlkh0000gn/T/go-build144784202=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

I add two lines in `.zshrc`：

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/ccode/go"
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
```

The command `go get golang.org/x/tour` was running with no error.

The strange thing is:
`echo $GOROOT` will display a blank line
And `echo $GOPATH` is consistent with `go env`.

Comment: Did you run `source` command after changing `.zshrc` file? Also, try to write to `.bash_profile` file similar lines as `.zshrc` is storing. And then `$ source ~/.bash_profile`. Lemme know if it won't help

Comment: @Mykhailo Tkachenko Thx for your remind, but I have used the ```source``` command before, and I have tried both ```.zshrc``` and ```.bash_profile```

Comment: Well, there is my `bash_profile` file and after source command every env var is not empty:
`export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
export GOROOT=$HOME/go
`

Comment: remove the double codes in the your export command. This worked for me.. !!

Answer (score 2):

May be you explicitly enable go module through GO111MODULE = on, then tour's code downloaded in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tour@v0.0.0-20191002171047-6bb846ce41cd` directory, but the tour program lookup tour src code dir through ctx.Import,at this time will only from `$GOROOT/src/golang.org/x/tour` or `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tour`, but not from `$GOPATH/PKG/mod`, so lead to can not find the tour src code dir.

Solution:

Solution 1: copy `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tour@v0.0.0-20191002171047-6bb846ce41cd` to `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tour`

Solution 2: modify the tour source local.go file

```golang
func findRoot() (string, error) {
    ...

    if os.Getenv("GO111MODULE") == "on" {
        pkgDir := filepath.Join(os.Getenv("GOPATH"), "pkg", "mod")
        cfg := &packages.Config{Mode: packages.LoadFiles, Dir: pkgDir}
        pkgs, _ := packages.Load(cfg, basePkg)
        for _, pkg := range pkgs {
            for _, goFile := range pkg.GoFiles {
                root := filepath.Dir(goFile)
                if isRoot(root) {
                    return root, nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "", fmt.Errorf("could not find go-tour content; check $GOROOT and $GOPATH")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem. And the problem is still not solved following Andy's answer. I checked the code of findRoot function in local.go file, it relies on build.Default, which is the return value of build.defaultContext(). It returns the default context which reads GOPATH from environment variables. And from the source code [build/build.go](https://golang.org/src/go/build/build.go) I see:

```
func defaultContext() Context {

    var c Context

    c.GOARCH = envOr("GOARCH", runtime.GOARCH)
    c.GOOS = envOr("GOOS", runtime.GOOS)
    c.GOROOT = pathpkg.Clean(runtime.GOROOT())
    c.GOPATH = envOr("GOPATH", defaultGOPATH())

    // code omitted

    return c

}
```

However, when we set GOPATH using `go env -w GOPATH="/Users/elk/ccode/go"` command, this value is saved only in go env, not in your system environment. So when you run the tour, since GOPATH is empty, it uses default path value, usually `/Users/elk/go`, which results in failure to find tour content.

This could be because "the tour of go" is written in 2011, when we still need to set GOPATH environment variable at that time. But later Go improved settings, but the legacy code in tour of go did not change accordingly.

So a quick solution is setting GOPATH variable in your .bashrc file. Or just `export GOPATH="Users/elk/ccode/go"` in the command line for temporary use, before you run the tour program.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that encounters this issue and just wants to run the tour, you can always navigate to `$HOME\go\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\tour@version` and then do `go run .`

Answer (score -1):

Try these steps:

1. set `GO111MODULE` off

```
   export GO111MODULE=off
```

2. make sure you are not inside the `$GOPATH` directory (if you are, just run `cd ~`)
3. run the `go get` command

```
   go get golang.org/x/tour
```